# Change NA to blank in date time in R

Tags: r, na

This might be a simple question but I have tried a few things and they're not working. 
I have a large data frame with date/time formats in. An example of my data frame is:

```
  Index       FixTime1                  FixTime2
    1     2017-05-06 10:11:03               NA
    2            NA              2017-05-07 11:03:03
```

I want to remove all NAs from the dataframe and make them "" (blank). I have tried:

```
df[is.na(df)]<-""
```

but this gives the error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(value) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Again, this is probably very simple to fix but can't find how to do this, while keeping each of these columns in time/date format

Comment: You have a `POSIXlt` cclass.  Change it to character class

Comment: You would have to convert all your dates to characters to do that. What is wrong with having NAs?

Comment: I can't have NAs as I'm doing an if statement in a loop after and it breaks because of the NA

Comment: You can use `& !is.na(` to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution on a toy dataset, adapt this code to your needs:

```
df<-data.frame(date=c("01/01/2017",NA,"01/02/2017"))
df
        date
1 01/01/2017
2       <NA>
3 01/02/2017
```

From factor to character, and then remove `NA`

```
 df$date <- as.character(df$date)
 df[is.na(df$date),]<-""
 df
            date
    1 01/01/2017
    2           
    3 01/02/2017
```

In your specific example, this could be fine:

```
df_2<-data.frame(Index=c(1,2),
+                FixTime1=c("2017-05-06 10:11:03",NA),
+                FixTime2=c(NA,"2017-05-07 11:03:03"))


df_2<-data.frame(lapply(df_2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df_2[is.na(df_2$FixTime1),"FixTime1"]<-"" 
df_2[is.na(df_2$FixTime2),"FixTime2"]<-""
df_2
  Index            FixTime1            FixTime2
1     1 2017-05-06 10:11:03                    
2     2                     2017-05-07 11:03:03
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace`

```
df[] <- replace(as.matrix(df), is.na(df), "")
df
#   Index            FixTime1            FixTime2
#1     1 2017-05-06 10:11:03                    
#2     2                     2017-05-07 11:03:03
```